# ¿error para clasificar string?

Tags: c++, string

*tengo el siguiente codigo ,compilo y me lanza una gran cantidad de errores no se como solucionarlo  el error es "el string es muy grande" ese una lista ,la voy a dejar acá abajo*
es raro por el hecho de que no se como solucionarlo y agrandar el string si puedo usar unsigned o algo asi para corregirlo..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

[image: error to string]
*a.cpp:59:24: warning: character constant too long for its type*

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <windows.h> 
        
    using namespace std;
        
    void ip_aleatory(long ip){
        
         
            volatile int n1[ip];
            volatile int n2[ip];
            volatile int n3[ip];
            volatile int n4[ip];
            
            string  IPs[ip]; 
            string  IPc[ip];
            string  IPa[ip];
            
            int k = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int t = 0;
    
            srand(time(NULL)); 
        
            for (int i = 0; i != ip; ++i)
            {
        
              n1[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
              n2[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
              n3[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
              n4[i] = 0 + rand() % (255); 
          
            }
        
            
            for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){
        
        
             IPs[i] = to_string(n1[i]) + '.' +
                      to_string(n2[i]) + '.' +
                      to_string(n3[i]) + '.' +
                      to_string(n4[i]) ;
        
           }
           for (int i = 0; i <ip; ++i){
    
                (n1[i]>=0   and n1[i]<=127) ? IPc[i]="A":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
                (n1[i]>=128 and n1[i]<=191) ? IPc[i]="B":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
                (n1[i]>=192 and n1[i]<=233) ? IPc[i]="C":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
                (n1[i]>=224 and n1[i]<=239) ? IPc[i]="D":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
                (n1[i]>=240 and n1[i]<=255) ? IPc[i]="E":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
           }
    
    
           for (int l = 0; l < ip; ++l){
             
              if (IPs[i] =='127.0.0.0')
             {
               continue;
             }
             else if (IPs[i] =='0.0.0.0')
             {
               continue;
             }
             else if (IPs[i] =='3.0.0.0')
             {
               continue;
             }
             else if (IPs[i] =='15.0.0.0')
             {
               continue;
             }
             else if (IPs[i] =='56.0.0.0')
             {
               continue;
             }
             else if (IPs[i] =='10.0.0.0')
             {
               continue;
             }
             else if (IPs[i] =='192.168.0.0')
             {
               continue;
             }
             else if (IPs[i] =='172.16.0.0')
             {
               continue;
             }
             else if (IPs[i] =='100.64.0.0')
             {
               continue;
             }
             else{
    
               IPs[i] = IPa[i];
               j++;
    
             }
    
           }
        
           for ( int i = 0; i < ip; ++i)
           {
               for ( j = i+1; i < ip; ++j)
               {
    
                 if(IPs[i] == IPs[j]){
    
                  k = j;
    
                   while(k < ip){
    
                      IPs[k] = IPs[k+1];
    
                      ++k;
                     }
    
                     --ip;
                      --j;
     
    
                 }
                   
               }
           }
    
           for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i)
           {
             t += sizeof(IPs[i]);
           }
     
    
          cout<<"loading";
          Sleep(1000);
          cout<<".";
          Sleep(1000);
          cout<<".";
          Sleep(1000);
          cout<<".";
          cout<<endl;
    
    
          for (int i=0;i<ip;++i){
    
            cout <<"["<<i+1<<"]"<<"["<<IPc[i]<<"]"<< IPs[i] << '\n';
            Sleep(500);
    
           }
    
         
          cout<<"clean";
          Sleep(2000);
          cout<<".";
          Sleep(2000);
          cout<<".";
          Sleep(2000);
          cout<<".";      
          system("cls");
    }
    void test_case(){
    
      long ip;
      cin>>ip;
      ip_aleatory(ip);
    
     }
    int main (){
    
    
      system("color 6");
      test_case();
     
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *el error es "el string es muy grande"*

Mentira. Lee bien: "**Character constant** is too long for its type".

Te traduzco al mensaje: "La constante de **carácter** es demasiado larga para su tipo". Un carácter no es una cadena (*string*).

---

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) los literales de texto (cadenas) se encierran entre comillas dobles (`"`) mientras que los literales de carácter se encierran entre comillas simples (`'`). Pero hay una excepción con estas últimas.

Las comillas simples se pueden usar para representar un literal multicarácter, cuyo tipo será entero:

```
int cafe = 'CAFE'; // la variable 'cafe' tendrá 1128351301 como valor
```

Los enteros (`int`) pueden almacenar 32 bits, que son 4 bytes... en cambio tu literal multicarácter intenta ser de 10 (`'172.16.0.0'`) u 11 (`'192.168.0.0'`) caracteres, por ello te dice que "La constante de carácter es demasiado larga para su tipo".

Comment: gracias ,no sabia  que había una diferencia entre comillas simples y comillas dobles

Answer (score 4):

Hola tiene ese error xq las cadenas deben estar entre comillas dobles ejemplo

```
  if (IPs[i] =="127.0.0.0")
             {
               continue;
             }
```

debe hacer esto en todas las condiciones, Saludos

Comment: gracias no sabia porque no me funcionaba

Comment: Por nada me alegro que haya resuelto